# O365 API, python sendmail:: Throttle Error: Application is over its IncomingBytes limit

Tags: django, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I'm receiving this throttling error and there is no mention anywhere regarding why this error occurs.

```
Error Message: Application is over its IncomingBytes limit.
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: ditto, from the ruby gem. I get a `429 ApplicationThrottled` error code but it isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs